# How to disable autoescaping in form_row() in Symfony 2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I'm trying to print a field using `form_row()` without autoescaping `|raw`

autoescaping is enabled already enabled in the project, I want to disable it only in the search field

the form:

```
// $builder ...

    /** @Ignore */
     $placeholder = '&#xf142;';

     $builder->add('query', 'search', [
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => [
           'placeholder' => $placeholder
         ],
        'label' => 'search'
     ]);
```

I am using `{{ form_rest(form) }}` to print all the fields, but I want to disable auescaping only on `search` which is the last field.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.query)|raw }}
```

I tried `{{ form_row(form.query|raw) }}` also

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't chuckle with HTML escape sequences. Today your page should be in UTF-8 and as a result, you can simply put the whole byte sequence in your placeholder and the browser will render it correctly, if the font is installed.

```
$builder->add('query', 'search', [
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => [
        'placeholder' => "\xEF\x85\x82"
    ],
    'label' => 'search'
]);
```

**Mind the double quotes**

Comment: It worked, but I still wonder if it is possible to make twig filter in the `form_row()`